# JApplet - super.paint(); causes flicker

Tags: java, swing, paint, flicker, japplet

I'm writing a JApplet right now, and whenever I call super.paint(), the applet flickers.
I am using double buffering (drawing to an image, and then rendering that image), but I think super.paint() is clearing the screen or something, defeating my double buffer.

I know I'm supposed to use paintComponents(), but for some reason, when I call "currentScreen.Draw(g)," it won't show the screen's draw.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{   

    super.paint(g);//Remove this and it works, but the JApplet background color will be gone, and everything will be white.

    currentScreen.Draw(g);
}
```

Screen Draw Method

```
public void Draw(Graphics g)
{

    if(buffer != null)
        g.drawImage(buffer, 150, 0, null);
    //g.drawString(drawstring, x, y);
}
```

Comment: Don't use double buffering, unless you really have to. JPanels are already double buffered by default.
Also, yes, you should use paintComponents().

Comment: @iAndrOidOs: paintComponents is an entirely different and inappropriate method to use. `paintComponent` is what the OP should use instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use paint and don't draw directly in the JApplet. Instead draw in a JPanel's paintComponent method and call super.paintComponent(g) as the first line of that method. Add that JPanel to your JApplet's contentPane to allow the applet to display it.

**Edit 1**
Also you can't use paintComponent**s** for this as this does something entirely different. Again use paintComponent but only in a component that derives from JComponent such as a JPanel (or a JComponent itself).

**Edit 2** 
Also always put an @Override above your paintComponent method to be sure that you are in fact overriding the super method.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I use paintComponents, my "Screen" class won't draw.  It's essentially a class with an Init(), Update(Graphics), and Draw(Graphics) functions.  It also has two variables, Image buffer and Graphics buffer_g, which are the buffer variables for the screen.  In the draw function, it just draws the buffer, and when the mouse is clicked/dragged, it adds lines to the buffer.

When using paitnComponents, this doesn't work.

Comment: @user830713: Please **re-read** my answer. Did you see my comment about not using "paintComponents"?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the "use a JPanel" part.  It works perfectly now!  Thanks!

Comment: paintComponent`s`, @Override +1