# How to stop moving image in a JApplet from flickering

Tags: java, applet, japplet

I managed to create a (basic) animated JApplet for the first time in 3 years, but I am annoyed with the image flickering when it moves. The Timer object is what is making the image move, and my private inner class "TimerListener" is responsible for the animated motion of the moving image.

Here is the code of my TimerListener class, where I think this problem may be able to be solved:

```
@Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawImage(smileyFace.getImage(), xCoord, yCoord, this);
    }

    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            //Following if-else manipulates Y coordinate
            if (goingUp) {
                if (yCoord > minY) {
                    yCoord -= move;
                } 
                else {
                    goingUp = false;
                }
            } else {
                if (yCoord < (getContentPane().getHeight() - (smileyFace.getIconHeight()+ Y_OFFSET))) {
                    yCoord += move;
                } 
                else {
                    goingUp = true;
                }
            }

            //Following if-else manipulates X coordinate
            if (goingSideways) {
                if (xCoord > 0) {
                    xCoord -= move;
                } 
                else {
                    goingSideways = false;
                }
            } else {
                if (xCoord < (getContentPane().getWidth() - (smileyFace.getIconWidth() + X_OFFSET))) {
                    xCoord += move;
                } 
                else {
                    goingSideways = true;
                }
            }

            repaint();
        }
    }
```

If it helps, here is a screenshot of my JApplet - in this case, the troll face should be moving in the black area, and bouncing off the sides as it hits them:

[image]

For those of you who want to run and test the JApplet, you can get the Netbeans project from https://github.com/rattfieldnz/Java_Projects/tree/master/JAppletAnimation.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004866/japplet-super-paint-causes-flicker?rq=1 the problem is you are repainting the whole applet.

Comment: @arynaq Thanks for that, it works very nicely :). Will now close this question, and 'credit' you with the answer.

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I was asked by my professor to create an Applet... I haven't really been told why applets shouldn't be used anymore. I guess the purpose of creating this applet was for me to remember how they are made. I could easily turn this into a standalone Java app.

Comment: @AndrewThompson If you wanted to make an applet-like application in the browser, what would you recommend to use? I know a combination of HTML5, CSS3, and Javascript would work nicely here..

Comment: *"..HTML5, CSS3, and Javascript.."*  Sounds good here.

Comment: For those of you who want to replicate this in HTML5, CSS3, and Javascript, the following link is a good starting point... http://physicscodes.com/bouncing-ball-simulation-in-javascript-on-html5-canvas/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the user 'arynaq', I have fixed my problem. I put the following paint method:

```
@Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawImage(smileyFace.getImage(), xCoord, yCoord, this);
    }
```

...into an inner class which extends JPanel (notice how I changed 'paint' to 'paintComponent'):

```
class ImagePanel extends JPanel
    {

        public ImagePanel()
        {
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(smileyFace.getImage(), xCoord, yCoord, this);
        }

        @Override
        public void setBackground(Color bg) {
            super.setBackground(bg); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }


    }
```

... then added it to my JApplet via it's init() method (I'm not sure if I'd be correct by calling this the JApplet's constructor...):

```
@Override
public void init() {

    smileyFace = new ImageIcon("images/happyFace.png");
    **add(new ImagePanel());**
    timerDelay = 10;
    timer = new Timer(timerDelay, new TimerListener());
    timer.start();

    //getContentPane().setBounds(0, 0, CONTENTPANE_WIDTH, CONTENTPANE_HEIGHT);
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    //maxY = getContentPane().getHeight();
    minY = 0;

    xCoord = 0;
    yCoord = 0;
    move = 2;

}
```

You can see it running by cloning [my GitHub JApplet project](https://github.com/rattfieldnz/Java_Projects/tree/master/JAppletAnimation) and running it in NetBeans :).