# getGraphics from panel returns null

Tags: java, swing, graphics, nullpointerexception, draw

so I have class Board that extends JApplet and in it's constructor I make a JPanel that I'll later draw boxes on, but when I try to do getGraphics it returns null :/

```
JPanel panel;
public Board(int x, int y, int wolfNumber, int hareNumber){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;

    wolvesCoords = new int[wolfNumber][2];
    haresCoords = new int[hareNumber][2];

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setVisible(true);

    add(panel);
}


public synchronized void write(int xx, int yy, Color c){
    int width=panel.getWidth()/x;
    int height=panel.getHeight()/y;

    Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
    System.out.println(g);

    g.setColor(c);

    g.drawRect(xx*width, yy*height, width, height);
    g.fillRect(xx*width, yy*height, width, height);


}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
        super.paint(g);
}
```

It gives nullpointerexception at line g.setColor(c) as g is null.

Comment: What is this `write` method? Why aren't you calling the drawing code in the `paint` method with that `Graphics` object?

Comment: write method paints on the board. I don't call paint because g is null and that is my current problem.

Comment: No, don't call `paint` yourself, Java will call `paint` for you automatically. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html

Comment: Why would I call drawing code in the paint method? I need to draw only when the method write is called, not when the app starts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JApplet - super.paint(); causes flicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004866/japplet-super-paint-causes-flicker)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `Graphics` object wrong. Instead of calling `write` from wherever you call it, instead override `paintComponent`. You could do something like:

```
private int xx;
private int yy;
private Color c;

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if(c != null) {
        int width=panel.getWidth()/x;
        int height=panel.getHeight()/y;

        g.setColor(c);

        g.drawRect(xx*width, yy*height, width, height);
        g.fillRect(xx*width, yy*height, width, height);
    }
}

public void write(int xx, int yy, Color c) {
    this.xx = xx;
    this.yy = yy;
    this.c = c;
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: Please don't forget to add the super's paintComponent call in your override. Otherwise 1+ for your answer.

Comment: I like this solution, however when I call repaint the method painComponent is not called. Why would that be?

Comment: @user3369008: if you spell it `painComponent` it won't be called. Be careful with your spelling, and make sure that your method has an `@Override` annotation on top of it. His recommendations and mine are the same, except he needs to add a super call in his method override.

Comment: Actually this error shows up when I try to add override - method does not override or implement a method from a supertype. Could it be that I am extending JApplet? I have to though

Comment: getGraphics is not an appropriate means to perform painting in Swing, you won't know when the component needs to be repainted and the contents will be over painted without your knowledge

Comment: Based on your last comment, don't override paint of top level components, like JApplet, instead, use something like JPanel to one form your custom painting and add it to your top level container

Comment: Hmm ok, it is called now, however there is absolutely no change on screen - it stays gray. When I added JLabels with red background to the panel to test if it displays at all it was red. Any idea?

Comment: @user3369008 The problem is what MadProgrammer said; don't override paint of top level components. However I don't have enough of your code to be able to fix it, but I think you should be able to at this point.

Answer (score 3):

Yours is a common problem and question and is yet another reason why you shouldn't use a Graphics object obtained by calling `getGraphics()` on a component. Another reason you shouldn't do this is that if you are successful at getting a non-null Graphics object (which is only available **after** the component has been rendered), it will not persist, and your image can turn null if any repaints occur.

Instead do what the tutorials advise you to do: Draw with the Graphics object provided to you in the JPanel's paintComponent method. If you want to draw a fixed background, then do so in a BufferedImage, and then draw that BufferedImage in the paintComponent method.

---

**Edit**
You ask:

> Why would I call drawing code in the paint method? I need to draw only when the method write is called, not when the app starts.

Because that is how Swing graphics is done, because doing it your way is rife with problems (which you're already experiencing). Again, don't guess at this stuff -- read the tutorials where it is all well explained for you.

---

**Edit**
You state in comment:

> Actually this error shows up when I try to add override - method does not override or implement a method from a supertype. Could it be that I am extending JApplet?

Yes, exactly so.

> I have to though

Yes, you have to have a class that extends JApplet in order to produce JApplets, but you don't have to and in fact **shouldn't** paint directly in them. Instead create a separate class that extends JPanel, and do your graphics inside of that class's `paintComponent` method. Then display that JPanel in your applet.

Comment: I want to use getGraphics however, can you explain "after the component has been rendered" ? Is my panel not rendered in this example? What should I do to render it?

Comment: @user3369008: Again, **don't** use `getGraphics()`. That is not how you should be doing Swing Graphics. Period.

Comment: @user3369008: please check out [these links](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info). Please also search this site for similar questions and answers, since this has all been hashed and rehashed here many times.

Comment: @user3369008: please see edit to answer regarding your latest comment about overriding applets.

Comment: I voted to close as duplicate of a question, which, surprising no one, @HovercraftFullOfEels has the accepted answer.